# list.files function - to return only exact file name with different years

Tags: r

So I have a list of files of the same pattern i.e. `IceExt_1950`, `IceExt_1951` etc to 2013.

When I use `sort(list.files(dataDir, IceExt_))` it returns all the files of three different types of variables:

```
IceExt_; Sum_IceExt_; Win_IceExt_
```

Is there a way to only return `IceExt_` files from 1950-2013 without listing the other variations of the file name?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pattern` argument is a regular expression so you should just be able to match the empty space at the start of the string using the caret operator `^` because no other files start with `"IceExt"`, like this...

```
list.files( dataDir , pattern = "^IceExt_" )
```

Comment: Is there also a way of ignoring certain file names? I.e. read in everything apart from `IceExt_` ?